# Stimulus Check Eligibility as 22yr Old College Student

Tags: united-states, income-tax, student, covid-19, stimulus

I am a 22 year old college student. My mom has not claimed me on her taxes since 2015. I have claimed independent since I turned 18. I do not live with her, she does not support me. I am a full time student & I have a full time job. I claim HOH every year. For FAFSA/NYS TAP purposes I am forced to file for financial aide as a dependent. Will this effect me receiving a stimulus check.

I am also an expectant mother, when I filed my 2020 taxes I did not know I was expecting. Should I amend my taxes? Will I qualify for this stimulus check? I have been severely impacted by COVID19.

Comment: Just to clarify because it might come up in the answers: You filed your 2019 taxes, not your 2020 taxes. 2019 taxes are what we’re due April 15 (now extended to July). You will file your 2020 taxes sometime between January and April 2021. That matters because if you don’t qualify based on 2019 taxes  you might in 2020 and will get the money in 2021.

Comment: The fact that your mom has not claimed you as a dependent does not meant that she *can't* claim you. What matters is whether your mom *can* claim you (i.e. whether she meets the conditions in the law to claim you). If she *can* claim you, you are not eligible for the stimulus payment even if she doesn't actually claim you.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency requirements for the FAFSA are slightly different than for federal taxes. Regardless, your FAFSA status has no impact on your federal taxes.

If no one can claim you for 2019, and you stated that no one could claim you when you filed, the IRS will send you the check in 2019. You should also get the $500 child stimulus credit when you file for 2020 next Spring.

> Should I amend my taxes?

The only reason you would amend your taxes (regarding the stimulus credit) is if you incorrectly checked the box that states "someone can claim me as a dependent".